# Calculating grid cords from (x, y) position C++

Tags: c++, coordinate-systems

I have an array[15][15] with path for my object. 0 is wall, anything else makes path (1->2->3->...->end). It's a reflection of the game field of 450px x 450px(30px x 30px is one field).

For array[15][15] looking like this:

> 080000000000000
>   010111011101110
>   010101010101010
>   010101010101010
>   010101010101010
>   010101010101010
>   010101010101010
>   010101010101010
>   010101010101010
>   010101010101010
>   010101010101010
>   010101010101010
>   010101010101010
>   011101110111010
>   000000000000090

I get:
[image: map2]

My object moves with some velocity * speed:

```
void Enemy::move()
{
    this->get_dir();
    this->x += this->velX * this->speed; // velX = -1 is left, 1 is right
    this->y += this->velY * this->speed; // velY = -1 is up, 1 is down
}
```

get_dir() checks what direction (velocity) it should set, like this:

```
void Enemy::get_dir()
{  
    Point p; // {x, y} struct

    p = this->get_grid(); // it tries to calculate X, Y axis into an array number
    if (p.y < 14 && path_grid[p.y + 1][p.x] - 1 == path_grid[p.y][p.x])
    {
        this->velY = 1;
        this->velX = 0;
        return;
    }
    /* same goes for rest of directions */

    this->velX = this->velY = 0; // if none matched it stops (reached end)
    return;
}

Point Enemy::get_grid()
{
    int x, y;

    for(y = 0;y < 15;y++)
    {
        if (this -> y >= y * 30 && this->y < (y + 1) * 30) break;
    }

    for(x = 0;x < 15;x++)
    {
        if (this -> x >= x * 30 && this->x < (x + 1) * 30) break;
    }

    return make_point(x, y);
}
```

But as you may notice, this will lead for my object to follow path like this:
[image: path]

Because it checks top left corner, and if I move right it should change the origin point, but I can't figure out how to do it. When I tried adding 30 (object bitmap size) if it goest right, it stops at the up -> right corner. What's a solution in here?

Comment: it might be me, but i would find the code much easier to read if you used parentheses to group those sub-expressions... also, names are important: how should we interpret `get_grid()`, whose result is being assigned to a `Point`? is it like `get_position_in_grid()`?

Comment: even the introduction sounds quite unclear to me: "I have an array[15][15] with path for my object. 0 is wall, anything else makes path (1->2->3->...->end)." what does this mean? can you please rephrase?

Comment: It's a shame you have left out all the other cases by saying "same goes..." because that is probably the key to finding your error.

Comment: OK, let's see if I managed to interpret it correctly: each cell in the 2D array `path_grid` contains a number. if the number is 0, that cell is a wall - can't go further. if the number is anything else, that cell is free - can go further. plus, it seems you show only the case where the object is moving down, but your picture shows you are having troubles when the object is moving *up*

Comment: My interpretation is that the path is laid out already.  Path cell 1 is number 1, the next is 2, 3, 4, 5...  If you look at the cell test where velocity is updated, it's all predetermined by the next cell being the current cell plus 1.

Comment: @paddy: right, I get it now

Comment: @AndyProwl But next thing you know, the question has been updated and that is not the case.  All intermediate path nodes appear to be `1`.

Comment: @paddy: no, I don't get it anymore. if the path is laid out already, why not having a vector of 2D grid coords and follow them instead of updating velocity etc? i thought the point was finding the path

Comment: I have the damn path, now I have to follow it but only data I have is object position x, y from [0, 450] and field ID (path[0-14][0-14]).

Comment: @Deith: are you trying to *find* the path or to *follow* a path you already determined?

Comment: I have the path, I just have to follow it.

Comment: @Deith: ok so 1) don't tag the question as "path-finding", and 2) why don't you encode a path in a 1D vector, where the i-th element of the vector is a 2D point containing the i-th (x,y) grid position of the path?

Comment: @Deith: anyway, even with the design you currently have, it seems that the wrong decision of going right is made in the code which you have replaced with `/* same goes for rest of directions */`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have removed most of my answer, as it appears to misunderstand the question.  But I will leave this part about your `get_grid` function being crazy.  Just use maths (I assume that `x` and `y` are integers):

```
Point Enemy::get_grid()
{
    return make_point(x / 30, y / 30);
}
```

Furthermore, if you want to take your grid position and show it in the centre of a tile where each tile is 30 pixels square, then do this:

```
int pixelX = gridX * 30 + 15;
int pixelY = gridY * 30 + 15;
```

Comment: i think he's not trying to *find* the path at all, which is why he is subtracting 1: he has the path already encoded in the 2D array in a way that if path[x1][y1] = path[x2][y2] + 1, then location (x1, y1) follows location (x2, y2) in the path. that's basically the assumption you made originally if i understood your comments correctly. so the velocity doesn't really matter here, he is using it only as a (arguable) way to update the location and he is computing it *based on the path he already has*. i think the design is wrong, but assuming this design, the bug is in the code which is not shown

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I didn't see additional discussion til after I had answered.  Was taking a bit of a stab.  The question is poorly worded, and only seems to show irrelevant information.  I'll remove everything except my `get_grid` replacement.

Comment: i guess you can't be blamed. the question is tagged as "path-finding", while this is not even a path-finding problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to find next open position from grid but should keep track of last move just so you don't backtrack, for example:

```
void movePlayer(){
  const GridMap& gridMap = getGridMap(); //returns the 14x14 grid
  const Position& currentPosition = getCurrentPosition(); //returns the current player position
  const Position& previousPosition = _getPreviousPosition(); //private helper func
  //returns a list of position where the current player at the given position can move to

  //at point (x,y) you can move to NORTH,SOUTH,EAST, or WEST one unit, from the gridMap
  //using the currentPosition, return the list of cells that the player at the given position can move to.
  const PositionList& currentMovablePositions = _getMovablePosition(currentPosition,gridMap);
  //return the first matching position that isn't currentPosition or previousPosition
  const Position& nextMovePosition = _getNextMovablePosition(currentMovablePosition,currentPosition,previousPosition);

  this->animateTo( nextMovePosition );
```

}